# VB .net windows form error : Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

My first time to create a vb.net windows forms system.

I found an error in Crystal Report. Not in web base.

> Error: [Could not load file or assembly
>   'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]

May I know my program loss something else?